# How do I write this cURL request correctly?

Tags: php, facebook, curl, bots, facebook-messenger

I am trying to complete a Facebook messenger bot based on this tutorial here: https://github.com/voronianski/simon-le-bottle/blob/master/GUIDE.md

As you can see in the last instruction, I must send a page access token via this cURL request in the following format:

```
curl -i \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
-X POST \
-d "{\"verifyToken\": \"YOUR VERIFY TOKEN\", \"token\": \"YOUR PAGE ACCESS TOKEN\"}" \
https://YOUR_GENERATED_URL.now.sh/token
```

Of course I replaced "YOUR VERIFY TOKEN" with the token I've generated and "YOUR PAGE ACCESS TOKEN" with the page access token that I've generated and "YOUR GENERATED URL" with my own url. However, I have tried multiple times and gotten various errors.

The first time I just tried copying and pasting the tokens and url into the input space and pasting the cURL request in that format. I received the following errors:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  
-bash: -H: command not found
-bash: -X: command not found
```

Basically all I received were commands not found. Then, I tried a different approach and removed the new line tabs and leaving only spaces like so

```
curl -i \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \  -X POST \ -d "{\"verifyToken\": \"randomverifytokenhere\", \"token\": otherrandomtokenhere\"}" https://myspecificurl.now.sh/token
```

Where of course I had actual working tokens and a website yet again. The commands seemed to work, but I got a whole new crop of errors like so:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -H
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Content-Type
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -d
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "verifyToken"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  "token"
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 21:51:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
```

If anyone could tell me exactly how I need to format and paste it into terminal to point where it works, that would be very helpful. Or if there's an easier, better way, I would definitely appreciate that. Every other step, up until the very last instruction, has been completed. The website has already been verified with webhook by Facebook, and I only use valid tokens and the specific website generated with "NOW". Thank you very much everyone, and I appreciate the help.

Comment: when you put the arguments on a single line, but left in the backslash escapes, you ended up escaping the `-`, which means `-H` stopped being a command switch/option, and become a plain string, and was interpreted as a host name, e.g. it (kinda) became equivalent of having done `curl dashH.com` rather than `curl -H` with no hostname.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarcB! It worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have no white space after the backslash at the end of the lines. When I highlight your command, there appears to be a space. If you remove those your problem should go away.

If you run it as a single line command, remove the backslashes that are at the end of each line.